# Ignoring new lines in python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a xml data, having multiple rows and I wan't certain processing on each row. But I was having trouble in fetching each row with tags `<Row>` to `</Row>`

```
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">LcolDefs:</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">Lkeywords:</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">TestProcedure</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s71"><Data ss:Type="String">LsetupTest:NMTA-1772</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s72"><Data ss:Type="String">DROP4</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s71"><Data ss:Type="String">TEX::stepCatch log::log notice "start NMTA-1772"</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:StyleID="s74">
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">LcolDefs:</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">Lkeywords:</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">TestProcedure</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s75"><Data ss:Type="String">Ljoin:Host</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s75"><Data ss:Type="String">Ljoin:Port</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:typeGroup</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:ipAddress</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:connectionType</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:port</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:username</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:password</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:id</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-code</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-pollGetNc</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-checkNe</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-checkDup</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-initializeVar</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-convertToJson</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
</Row>
```

I was playing with re.findAll to get a list of row wise data, but either it is not fetching copmplete data or fetching complete data just in a single list index

Trying with combinations like:

`re.findall('<Row.*(?:.|\n)+</Row>', table)
 re.findall('<Row(?:.|\n)?[^</Row>]*', table)`

But not working..

Comment: Can you provide a sample how your expected result should be?

Comment: @Ahsanul Haque : it should be a list having data between the each <Row></Row> tags.
In the data snippet, we have 3 rows, So I am expecting 3 list items carrying data for each row

Comment: Why don't you use a SAX parser or DOM with XPath?

Comment: You probably want to investigate re.DOTALL. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL "Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline."

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to parse it with regex. But I assume, you just want it for experiment. In that case, this should help:

```
import re
with open('your_file.xml','r') as f:
    file_content = f.read()
    result_list = re.findall(r'<Row.+?>((?:\n.*?)*)<\/Row>', file_content)
    for element in result_list:
        print element
        print "---------------------------->"
```

Output:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">LcolDefs:</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">Lkeywords:</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">TestProcedure</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>

---------------------------->

<Cell ss:StyleID="s71"><Data ss:Type="String">LsetupTest:NMTA-1772</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s72"><Data ss:Type="String">DROP4</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s71"><Data ss:Type="String">TEX::stepCatch log::log notice "start NMTA-1772"</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s73"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>

---------------------------->

<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">LcolDefs:</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">Lkeywords:</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">TestProcedure</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s75"><Data ss:Type="String">Ljoin:Host</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s75"><Data ss:Type="String">Ljoin:Port</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:typeGroup</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:ipAddress</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:connectionType</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:port</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:username</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:password</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s76"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:id</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-code</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-pollGetNc</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-checkNe</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-checkDup</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-initializeVar</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s77"><Data ss:Type="String">Lparam:-convertToJson</Data></Cell>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s70"/>

---------------------------->
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zm5bHU/1)